# The real line, topologically speaking, is the unique X.

Tags: general-topology

Find X.

And don't make reference to "unique one dimensional manifold" or "unique metricizible anything" as both manifolds and metrics depend on the real numbers, making the definition circular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real line is the unique connected, locally connected, separable, regular space such that the removal of any point results in exactly two connected components.

**Source:** S. P. Franklin & G. V. Krishnarao, *On the topological characterization of the real line*, J. London Math. Soc(2), 2 (1970), 589-591.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a linear order: [this paper by Bing](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308632?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) characterises the real line as the unique LOTS $X$ (linearly ordered topological space; a linearly ordered set in its order topology) which is separable connected and has no minimum or maximum.

This is really an order-theoretic characterisation, as separability and connectedness of a LOTS is also order theoretic. Any set $X$ that obeys is is even order isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so certainly homeomorphic.

Comment: This is fine: I just didn't want a circular definition, which manifolds and metric spaces obviously are wrt the reals.